# How to asynchronously interrupt an fs2 stream?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2, cats-effect

I'm trying to interrupt an fs2 stream with SignalRef. I set up and run the stream with the following. The stream should run when `switch` contains `false` and should interrupt when `switch` contains `true`

```
  import cats.effect.IO
  import fs2.Stream
  import fs2.concurrent.SignallingRef

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
  import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

  implicit val contextShift = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)
  implicit val timer = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)

  val switch: IO[SignallingRef[IO, Boolean]] = SignallingRef[IO, Boolean](false)

  val program: Stream[IO, Unit] = {

      val program: Stream[IO, Unit] =
        Stream
          .repeatEval(IO{
            println(java.time.LocalTime.now)
            println(switch.map(_.get).unsafeRunSync.unsafeRunSync)
          })
          .metered(1.second)

      program
        .interruptWhen(Stream.repeatEval(switch.map(_.get).unsafeRunSync))
    }
  
  program.compile.drain.unsafeRunAsync(() => _)
```

I then attempt to interrupt the stream with

```
switch.map(_.set(true).unsafeRunSync)
```

However, the stream keeps going. In stdout I see

```
15:58:33.048504
false
15:58:34.048760
false
15:58:35.049063
false
15:58:36.049356
false
15:58:37.049615
false
```

So apparently it's not picking up the switch to true?

Comment: Every time you call `map` on a **IO** you get a new value, because an **IO** is a recipe for a value. The power of **IO** is composition, you should never call  any of the `unsafe` methods, but rather compose your programs into a single one.

Answer (score 7):

There are several problems with your code.

First of all, please check the signature of `switch`:

```
val switch: IO[SignallingRef[IO, Boolean]] = SignallingRef[IO, Boolean](false)
```

Type of `SignallingRef` is wrapped into `IO`. It means that the creation of new `SignallingRef` is suspended until `IO` monad is evaluated (implicitly by `IO` program flow or explicitly by calling `unsafeRunXXX`). So more suitable name of this value would be probably `createSwitch`.

When you use `switch.map(_.get).unsafeRunSync` actually every time you're creating a new instance of `SignallingRef` with its default value `false`, so it's never get's evaluated to true.

The rule of thumb is that you should (almost) never call `unsafeRunXXX` methods up until you finish assembling your IO/Stream program and then you should run that kind of method once.

The right way to do it would be to create `switch` once in for-comprehension and then you could pass it to `program` as an argument.

I refactored your code a little bit to do what I think you intended to do and also added some clarification comments.

```
import cats.effect.IO
import fs2.Stream
import fs2.concurrent.SignallingRef

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

implicit val contextShift = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)
implicit val timer = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)

//I changed name to createSwitch, which I think reflect reality more
val createSwitch: IO[SignallingRef[IO, Boolean]] = SignallingRef[IO, Boolean](false)

val program: Stream[IO, Unit] = {

  //I pass here switch as method's param
  def program(switch: SignallingRef[IO, Boolean]): Stream[IO, Unit] =
    Stream
      .repeatEval {
        for { //I used for-comprehension to split IO into 3 statements
          switchValue <- switch.get //here I get value of switch
          _ <- IO(println(java.time.LocalTime.now)) //I split println into 2 separate statements
          _ <- IO(println(switchValue)) //because it's not a good practive to run 2 effect in single IO
        } yield ()
      }
      .metered(1.second)

  for {
    switch <- Stream.eval(createSwitch)
    //here I create effect to set switch to true after 10 seconds and then use start to run it
    //separate fiber in background. If I didn't do that it would just wait 10 sec and only then run program
    _ <- Stream.eval(switch.set(true).delayBy(10.seconds).start)
    _ <- program(switch).interruptWhen(switch)
  } yield ()

}

program.compile.drain.unsafeRunSync()
```

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I use my own kill switch for things like that:

```
final case class KillSwitch[F[_]](stream: Stream[F, Unit], switch: F[Unit])
object KillSwitch {

  def apply[F[_]: Sync]: F[KillSwitch[F]] =
    Ref.of(true).map(switch => KillSwitch(Stream.repeatEval(switch.get).takeWhile(identity).void, switch.set(false)))
}
```

I use it more or less like:

```
for {
  KillSwitch(kfStream, switch) <- KillSwitch[F]
  streamFiber <- yourStream.zip(kfStream).map(_._1).compile.drain.start
  // after a while
  _ <- switch // closes kfStream
  result <- streamFiber.join
} yield result
```

(let's say it's a pseudocode to show the idea).